# Upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 hangs

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

My jammy update got stuck while installing the upgrades without a clear reason (see screenshot). In the background of the image, the contents of syslog and in particular:

```
Aug 11 11:00:56 clapas pulseaudio[2427]: Error opening PCM device front:0: Invalid argument
Aug 11 11:00:56 clapas pulseaudio[2427]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Aug 11 11:00:56 clapas pulseaudio[2427]: Error opening PCM device front:0: Invalid argument
Aug 11 11:00:56 clapas pulseaudio[2427]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Aug 11 11:02:36 clapas gnome-shell[2661]: Some code accessed the property 'discreteGpuAvailable' on the module 'appDisplay'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Aug 11 11:02:38 clapas zeitgeist-datah[3105]: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:210: Error during inserting events: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.zeitgeist.EngineError.InvalidArgument: Incomplete event: interpretation, manifestation and actor are required
Aug 11 11:02:38 clapas systemd[2421]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Aug 11 11:02:38 clapas systemd[2421]: Started VTE child process 198019 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 197178.
Aug 11 11:02:38 clapas systemd[2421]: gnome-launched-org.gnome.Terminal.desktop-198013.scope: Succeeded.
Aug 11 11:02:56 clapas pulseaudio[2427]: Error opening PCM device front:0: Invalid argument
Aug 11 11:02:56 clapas pulseaudio[2427]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
```

Release upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04:

[image: Distribution Upgrade screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I did not get any answer, OK.
So, here is how I solved the issue...
I had to reboot into recovery mode and choose an older kernel version.
Then, I followed the hints given in this page:
https://linuxhint.com/fix-broken-ubuntu-22-04-without-reinstalling/
...which proved helpful!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to switch to other console, list processes (ps) and kill blocking one (save-param) and after reboot just sudo dpkg --configure -a